# How can I guarantee the integrity and consistency of “distant” relationships?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

We have a database structure like the one shown in the (very simplified) diagram below:

[image]

As you can see, there is a table `Categories`, holding data like this:

```
Id Description
1  Car
2  Truck
```

The table `VehicleParts` holds the data that correlates which *vehicle* has which *part*.

**My question**

How can I guarantee that one row in the `VehicleParts` table does not reference a `Version` of a `Car` and a `Part` of a `Truck` or vice versa?

Comment: I'm not clear on the relationship here. Can Cars not have Versions, and can Trucks not have Parts?

Comment: @RandolphWest Yes. `Car` and `Truck` are just example data of the table Categories. As they are only `1 to N` relationship, they can have 0 Models, 0 Versions, 0 Sets and 0 Parts; i.e. if the user add a new row on the categories table, "Motorcycles".

Comment: You might have to get creative with triggers and / or default constraints.

Comment: Yes, you add `CategoryID` to Versions, Parts and VehicleParts and modify Forein Key and Unique constraints appropriately.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Thanks for your comment, and the related question. So, adding CategoryID to Versions and Parts does not introduce some data redundancy? i.e. We can not assume that a Version that is related to a Model that is related to a Car is a Car?

Comment: Yes, you also modify the FKs to be composite (include the `CategoryID`). There is redundnancy but you can't avoid it, if you want to enforce this kind of constraint. The other way would be to use triggers or restrict access to stored procedures (for INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE in the related tables) that take care / enforce it.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Ah, I see. The comments on the linked question are about that as well... (btw awesome answer on the other question. It is very close to mine, and unfortunately I do not find it before posting).

Comment: See my answer there. I have also links to 4 or 5 similar questions. Your schema is a tiny bit different, it has 2 tables (Sets, Parts) in one side/path of the "diamond" shape. But it doesn't change the proposed solution.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Understood. The name of this kind of relationships is technically called "diamond shape"?

Comment: No, that's mine because the design looks like that of drawn on paper. I don't know an official/technical term.